# Integrate multiple dictionaries in django

Tags: django, list, dictionary

Really having trouble about list these days, I'm a developer from php looking a place in python. My question is in relation to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46693015/create-a-new-list-according-to-item-value/46693133#)

I now have a dictionary group by id_position and flag that contains order [Top, Right, Bottom, Left, Center]:

```
 a = {'41': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], '42': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], '43': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], '44': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}
```

and other dictionary that contains my id_position and status:

```
 b =  {'44': 'statusC', '42': 'statusB', '41': 'statusA', '43': 'statusC'}
```

I want to include dict A in my code to save dict B below.

```
 for pos, stat in B.items():
    MyModel.objects.create(position=pos, status=stat, Top = "" , Right="" Bottom = "", Left= "")
```

How can I make this wok?
Can you recommend study list where I can start to work from php to django.

**UPDATE:**
I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20072870/combining-two-dictionaries-into-one-with-the-same-keys) and added my code below:

```
c = {}
for key in set().union(a, b):
if key in a: c.setdefault(key, []).extend(a[key])
if key in b: c.setdefault(key, []).extend(b[key])
print(c)
```

and it returned:

```
  {
  '42': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 's', 't', 'a', 't', 'u', 's', 'B'],
  '41': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 's', 't', 'a', 't', 'u', 's', 'A'], 
  '44': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 's', 't', 'a', 't', 'u', 's', 'C'], 
  '43': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 's', 't', 'a', 't', 'u', 's', 'C']
}
```

my problem now is that my string is being separated

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're looking for...

something like this?:

```
Top=A[int(pos)][0]
Right=A[int(pos)][1]
Bottom=A[int(pos)][2]
Left=A[int(pos)][3]
```

hope it helps.

Comment: it returned `KeyError:id`

Comment: one of your dicts doesn't fit description given.

Comment: also i noticed that in B dict your keys are string and in A dict they are integers. updated the answer accordingly